# Gerrit Code review tool

Tags: gerrit

We are using git repository and we are thinking to use code review tool and came to know about gerrit.

Now or requirements are:

1. We want to keep the git repositories where they are.
2. We want to use gerrit to take changes which we want to review.

But i don't understand what is the purpose of projects inside the git folder of gerrit server.

Also when i run git-review more than once it used to ask that you have multiple commits and shows some commits id. Hence i don't understand what is the logic of git project under gerrit server.

My requirement is simple, I want to make a commit on local clone and do it's git review and once code is reviewed on gerrit, I want to git push it to my repository.

Consider my repo is here '/home/shailendra/repo/' and clone is at '/home/shailendra/clone/repo' and gerrit is running from '/home/shailendra/gerrit_server'

If anybody understood my concern please explain me that how can this be done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem is how to make Gerrit point to an already existing git repo

When you are setting up Gerrit on server it asked you for `Location of Git repositories   [git]:` if no input was provided it assumes default which is `/var/lib/gerrit/review_site`.

In your case I see it must be pointing to `/home/shailendra/repo/`

You can either change this in `gerrit.config` file which you can find by `find -t f -name gerrit.config` and make changes to the following property `gerrit.basePath` and restart gerrit

or you can create a symlink to your repo under `/var/lib/gerrit/review_site` i.e. `sudo ln -s /home/shailendra/repo` and restart...

Though I haven't tried any of these...I believe it would be worth a shot..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replication plugin to replicate your changes from Gerrit to to the original git repositories.

Work flow:

1. Create new project in Gerrit
2. Import current repositories
3. Ensure only Gerrit can push to the old repositories
4. Setup replication to push the new changes to the old repositories